# how to include an asterisk a url within Django?

Tags: django-templates

I have the following code in my Django template:

```
<a href="{% url myapp.views.myview foobar %}">
```

so, what's the right way to handle the situation where "foobar" contains an asterisk (for example, "*1234")?  At the moment, Django is throwing this error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'myapp.views.myview.myview' 
with arguments '(u'*86743',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly, You'd see this if you're specifying a url rule with a **\w** regex.   For example:`(r'^myview/(?P<myparam>\w.+)/$', 'myview')` would cause this. Broadening the regex a bit to allow the ampersand should cure your ills.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that one of the entries in your urlconf actually *matches* the arguments you pass. If you only allow digits (`[0-9]+`) then an asterisk won't match.